# RequestMappingHandlerMapping is truncating path for RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

I seem to be confused about how to add a RestController into my application. I'm pretty close here, but when hitting the url `http://localhost:8080/rest/username/test` I get the following in my logs.

`2015-10-27 20:12:23,427 26366 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/username/test reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain 
2015-10-27 20:12:23,427 26366 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'Rest' processing GET request for [/rest/username/test] 
2015-10-27 20:12:23,427 26366 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /username/test 
2015-10-27 20:12:23,428 26367 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/username/test] 
2015-10-27 20:12:23,428 26367 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/username/test] are [/**]`

I found many stackoverflow pages related to truncated path variables due to "dot"(.), but my path has no "dot" and just returns a string for now.

It seems to me that the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` object is truncating the path when trying to find a match to an appropriate method. I am just unsure as to why, and how to get it to work correctly.

**RestController**

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/{username}")
public class RestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test() {
    return "Rest controller data.";
}

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**rest-servlet.xml**

```
<!-- mvc config -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- scan for controller -->  
<context:component-scan base-package="abnd.pue.rest"/>
```

Comment: Don't put your context path in your controller's mapping. That is a deployment property. Your application should not know about it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. The issue is that the context path is a deployment property, and it should not be added to the controller's mapping.

The fix

**RestController**

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}")
public class RestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test() {
return "Rest controller data.";
}

}
```